# Obtener datos de objeto PHP pero tiene un array json al final

Tags: php, javascript, json, array, webservice

Buenas noches, tengo un problema al intentar obtener la respuesta de los webservices de afip. Mando una peticion al ws de afip y me devuelve lo siguiente.

[image: RespuestaWSAFIP]

Quiero obtener el error pero si ven, la respuesta del WS es un stdclass y abajo de todo un array JSON.

Como puedo hacer para acceder a los valores del arreglo stdclass?

Si hago un parseJSON(objeto); no hace nada, como que muere ahi. Y si intento acceder al arreglo me tira undefined. Y no puedo acceder a Code ni a Msg.

Comment: segun ese error hay un caracter inesperado en la linea 1, revisa alguna coma, comillas, numeral, algun signo raro

Comment: ¿Cómo estás consumiendo el webservice? ¿Podés mostrar tu código? ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: El framework que estás usando debe tener un método para parsear el objeto stdClass del response.

Comment: Victor, el caracter inesperado es porque parseJSON(string), recibe un string y lo convierte a json, pero como este tiene un objeto de stdclass y al final una linea de tipo json no lo comprende. Si fuera todo un stdclass no lanzaria el error.

Comment: @A.Cedano hago la consulta con ajax usando jquery, y el metodo para parsear es parseJSON(), cuando la consulta al webservice no tira error funciona bien, porque devuelve una cadena json(en ese caso no necesito parsear nada), pero cuando el webservice tira algun error me devuelve un stdclass y abajo me tira el json con algunos valores null.

Comment: Entonces me pregunto si no deberías modificar la lógica misma de la consulta al webservice, haciendo que en caso de error no devuelva un stdclass sino otro JSON. Luego al leer el JSON devuelto podrías determinar si se trata de una respuesta errónea o no. O bien manejar la lógica a través del código de la respuesta: `200` para respuestas satisfactorias u otro. Creo que todos los frameworks actuales traen funciones para eso.

Comment: Me pregunto por qué diablos un servicio web te devolvería un toString de una clase. ¿Es esto normal en esa API? Te recomendaría contactar con el soporte.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer no es nada fácil, ya que tienes un `var_dump`, no una serialización real de un objeto (PHP ofrece varios métodos para serializar y des-serializar como`json`, `serialize` o `wddx`, pero no es ninguno de ellos). Tendrás que hacerte tu propia función que saque los datos.

Para separar el *dump* del json, haz un *split* por `\n`. La última línea es el json, todas las anteriores el dump del objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Si la consulta la lanzas mediante Ajax creo que deberías agregarle un control de errores (en jQuery ".ajaxError()") donde recogerías y podrías analizar la cadena retornada por el webservices. 
Ignoro porqué te lanza el error pero al trabajar con datos **JSON** es muy fácil dañar su *exquisita* síntaxis debido sobre todo a trascodificaciones entre servidores al enviar/recibir datos (UTF-8 a ASCII y demás) y en las operaciones de lectura/escritura de archivos por la misma causa, puede que incluso una simple marca no visible (UTF sin BOM) en el archivo de donde hayas obtenido la cadena JSON, e incluso dependiendo del S.O. en el que trabaje el servidor: Windows, Linux, Unix, ... por caracteres de control (return, new line, ...)

JSON es una buena forma de transmitir información pero es bastante estricto con su síntaxis: unas comas simples, omitir el **0** inicial en decimales, *undefined* en vez de *null*, ... cualquier carácter de control.
Quizás debas buscar la cadena JSON enviada y asegurarte que no incluye ningún carácter especial o no permitido. Puede que te sirva de utilidad algún software de validación JSON o incluso herramientas online como:  http://json.parser.online.fr/